# Android Studio Secondary Activity Closes and Launches with no Audio Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an activity that launches on Button click and an audio service using MediaPlayer is started on onResume for the new activity. The audio service is stopped in the onPause method.

For some reason the activity's audio service does not start. Using log, it shows me that the new activity runs through the onCreate, onResume, onPause and onDestroy methods once before it is created again and stops at onResume, but without starting the audio service.

This only happens on some devices and emulators while it is working fine for others. As an example, it works fine on the emulator Pixel API 23, while it does not for Pixel C API 23. I have two friends who tried running my app on their physical phones, both of the same Samsung model. It works for one of them while it does not for the other. logcat shows no errors when testing on the emulator.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what could be causing this error?

I have tried `android:largeHeap="true"` in case it was a heap problem, but to no avail. minSDKVersion is set to 15.

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)